# ForeignKey relationship on two fields which are unique together

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'd like to make a relationship like so in django:

```py
class ColorModel(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(ArticleModel, to_field='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('article', 'color')

class TaillesModel(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(ColorModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(ColorModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

So each article has multiple colors, and each of those colors has multiple sizes in different quantities.

However, this gives me those errors:

```
Reverse accessor for 'TaillesModel.article' clashes with reverse accessor for 'TaillesModel.color'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'TaillesModel.article' or 'TaillesModel.color'.
front.TaillesModel.color: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'TaillesModel.color' clashes with reverse accessor for 'TaillesModel.article'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'TaillesModel.color' or 'TaillesModel.article'.
```

I don't understand what `related_name` is supposed to be set to here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in *reverse*. So it means that for a given `ColorModel` object, you can access the `TaillesModel`s that refer to that `ColorModel` through the `article` model, or the `color` model. By default these are given the name `modelname_set`, so in this case `colormodel_set`, but since there are two of them, that would clash.

You thus should define two different names, for example:

```
class TaillesModel(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        ColorModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tailles_as_articlecolor'
    )
    color = models.ForeignKey(
        ColorModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tailles_as_color'
    )
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`ColorModel`</s> to `Color`.